# How to get audio latency for bluetooth speaker

Tags: ios, swift, audio, bluetooth, latency

I'm developing application that can play local music as well youtube video and its working fine.

Now I connect my iPhone to bluetooth speaker and i want to calculate audio latency for bluetooth speaker.

How i can get latency for my connected bluetooth device?

Any suggestion or idea or article ?

Thank You.

Comment: audioSession.outputLatency ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya `audioSession.outputLatency` is the only way to get latency?